# No SSD TRIM script in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: 20.04, ssd, trim

I figured out that there is no `fstrim` script in `/etc/cron.weekly`. I've read that TRIM is automatically enabled for SAMSUNG SSD. I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and there is no fstrim script in all cron folders. In `/etc/fstab` `discard` isn't set either - but discard isn't recommended anyway.

I created now the fstrim script in `/etc/cron.weekly`. I hope that interferes with no other script or missed I something?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`fstrim` is managed by `systemctl`, not `cron`, and is defined by a systemd service unit called `fstrim.service` and a timer unit called `fstrim.timer`.

```
$ locate fstrim.service
...
/usr/lib/systemd/system/fstrim.service
```

Please use

```
$ systemctl status fstrim.timer
```

to check for the status of fstrim. It will show something like ...

```
● fstrim.timer - Discard unused blocks once a week
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/fstrim.timer; enabled; vendor preset: >
     Active: active (waiting) since Wed 2021-01-27 02:23:22 CET; 1 day 21h ago
    Trigger: Mon 2021-02-01 01:02:07 CET; 3 days left
   Triggers: ● fstrim.service
       Docs: man:fstrim

jan 27 02:23:22 discworld systemd[1]: Started Discard unused blocks once a week.
```

If that is not the same for you... the ssd might not be compatible.

Comment: Ah okay, thank you! Then the infos on many pages are obsolete. fstrim timer service is running on my system. I deleted the cron. :)